# MongoDB Aggregation - How to use $getfield to get a field from root Document with condition

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm starting to learn Aggregate in MongoDB. I have a simple doc as below, which has 2 fields, `name` and `examScores`. `examScores` is an `array` containing multiple documents:

```
[
  { 
    _id: ObjectId("633199db009be219a43ae426"),
    name: 'Max',
    examScores: [ 
      { difficulty: 4, score: 57.9 },
      { difficulty: 6, score: 62.1 },
      { difficulty: 3, score: 88.5 } 
    ] 
  },
  { 
    _id: ObjectId("633199db009be219a43ae427"),
    name: 'Manu',
    examScores: [ 
      { difficulty: 7, score: 52.1 },
      { difficulty: 2, score: 74.3 },
      { difficulty: 5, score: 53.1 } ] }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I query the maximum score of each person using `$unwind` and `$group`/`$max` as below:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$examScores"},
    {$group: {_id: {name: "$name"}, maxScore: {$max: "$examScores.score"}}}
])
{ _id: { name: 'Max' }, maxScore: 88.5 }
{ _id: { name: 'Manu' }, maxScore: 74.3 }
```

But I want the result also contains the `examScores.difficulty` field corresponding to `name` and `examScores.score`, like below:

```
[
  { _id: { name: 'Max' }, difficulty: 3, maxScore: 88.5 }
  { _id: { name: 'Manu' }, difficulty: 2, maxScore: 74.3 }
]
```

I know that I can use `$sort` + `$group` and `$first` to achieve this goal. But I want to use `$getField` or any other methods to get data from the root doc.

My idea is to use `$project` and `$getField` to get the `difficulty field` from the root doc (or `$unwind` version of the root doc) with the condition like `ROOT.name = Aggregate.name` and `Root.examScores.score = Aggregate.maxScore`.

It will look something like this:

```
{$project: 
          {name: 1, 
          maxScore: 1, 
          difficulty: 
                        {$getField: {
                         field: "$examScores.difficulty"
                         input: "$$ROOT.$unwind() with condition/filter"}
                        }
           }
}
```

I wonder if this is possible in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

1. `$unwind`
2. `$group` - Group by `name`. You need `$push` to add the `$$ROOT` document into `data` array.
3. `$project` - Set the `difficulty` field by getting the value of `examScores.difficulty` from the first item of the filtered `data` array by matching the `examScores.score` with `maxScore`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$examScores"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name"
      },
      maxScore: {
        $max: "$examScores.score"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id.name",
      maxScore: 1,
      difficulty: {
        $getField: {
          field: "difficulty",
          input: {
            $getField: {
              field: "examScores",
              input: {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$data",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.examScores.score",
                        "$maxScore"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EbUQKU8Za78)

---

**Solution 2: `$rank`**

1. `$unwind`
2. `$rank` - Ranking by partition `name` and sort `examScores.score` descending.
3. `$match` - Filter the document with `{ rank: 1 }`.
4. `$unset` - Remove `rank` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$examScores"
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$name",
      sortBy: {
        "examScores.score": -1
      },
      output: {
        rank: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rank: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "rank"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8qO2mIiWc12)

---

Opinion: I would say this approach:

1. `$sort` by `examScores.score` descending
2. `$group` by name, take the first document

would be much easier.

Comment: For Solution 2, in case possible that there is a person who has multiple documents with the highest score, you need the `$group` stage. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TGIkK0-Mhw6)

Comment: I tested Solution 1 but in the result, there isn't "difficulty" field, only two name fields are duplicated. Could you check the 1st solution again? Thank you!

Comment: Done update the Solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to `$unwind` and then rebuild the documents again via `$group` to achieve your desired results. I'd recommend avoiding that altogether.

Instead, consider processing the arrays inline using [array expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators). Depending on the version and exact results you are looking for, here are two starting points that may be worth considering. In particular the [$maxN operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/maxN-array-element) and the [$sortArray operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray) may be of interest for this particular question.

You can get a sense for what these two operators do by running an `$addFields` aggregation to see their output, [playground  here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NtdGlX08XQZ).

With those as a starting point, it's really up to you to make the pipeline output the desired result. Here is one such example that matches the output you described in the question pretty well ([playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JLLkD8Y8pX9)):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "relevantEntry": {
        $first: {
          $sortArray: {
            input: "$examScores",
            sortBy: {
              "score": -1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      difficulty: "$relevantEntry.difficulty",
      maxScore: "$relevantEntry.score"
    }
  }
])
```

Which yields:

```
[
  {
    "difficulty": 3,
    "maxScore": 88.5,
    "name": "Max"
  },
  {
    "difficulty": 2,
    "maxScore": 74.3,
    "name": "Manu"
  }
]
```

Also worth noting that this particular approach doesn't do anything special if there are duplicates. You could look into using `$filter` if something more was needed in that regard.